# No known class method for selector

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates, method-call

The .h file:

```
@interface WibraryViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {    
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicatorView;
}
+ (void) notifyServerOfFileOpening:(NSString *) docName;
```

The .m method:

```
+ (void) notifyServerOfFileOpening:(NSString *) docName
{
    NSLog(@"doc opened name = %@", docName);
}
```

The line in another class that generates the 'No known class method for selector' error:

```
[WibraryViewController notifyServerOfFileOpening];
```

I'm guessing this might have something to do with the fact that UIAlertViewDelegate delegate is being used but I haven't really grasped how delegates work yet. 
Of course, it could also be something entirely different.

I was hoping someone could point out the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to pass the "docName" parameter. You are calling

```
[WibraryViewController notifyServerOfFileOpening];
```

instead of

```
[WibraryViewController notifyServerOfFileOpening:@"YourDocName"];
```

Hope that helps ;)

Comment: Whoops - guess who is feeling rather stupid? Thank you very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as the site allows.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a parameter docName:

```
[WibraryViewController notifyServerOfFileOpening:yourDocName];
```

the selector you use currently is `notifyServerOfFileOpening`, but the selector you have to use is like `notifyServerOfFileOpening:`.